# Units when the axis is the log

Tags: siunitx, unit-of-measure

Not sure if this is the right forum but I saw some similar questions so here goes:

I want to plot the log of a positive quantity. What's the best approach to communicate units. For instance if I take a the log of conductivity, is it correct to label the axis as: `\log\,\sigma \; (S{\cdot}m^{-1})`?

Of course implicit in all this is that the quantity has been normalized using 1 unit.

Comment: This is indeed off-topic here. But if your data is in `\si{\siemens\per\metre}` you could label your axis as `\log(\frac{\sigma}{\qty{1}{\siemens\per\metre}})` or `\log(\frac{\sigma}{\si{\siemens\per\metre}})` or with a slash instead of the `\frac`, so `\log(\sigma / \si{\siemens\per\metre})`.

Comment: Technically you don‘t introduce a new unit, e.g. like moving from [m] (for meter) to [lg m] when you measure say L You just display the measured value in a different way. Though @Skillmon s remark on fractions is useful, from a communication point of view I think it‘s overdone: you still talk about a measurement of say in [m], displayed on a logarithmic scale. So I‘d still label the axis „L [m]“, if you measure L in meters. The logarithm display should be self-evident: if it‘s not, all hope is gone for the reader ;-) // BTW „L [m]“ has already no dimension, so lg is fine on it.

Comment: @MS-SPO agreed, though it depends on the tick-values. If they are something like `10, 100, 1000` yours is the correct approach, if they are `1, 2, 3` (for log10) then mine is the correct one.

Comment: @Skillmon. Thank you. This seems good. And yes the scale is linear (not logarithmic).

Comment: @MS-SPO also, iirc, using `L [m]` is not SI-conform, while `[L] = m` this doesn't work the other way round. You shouldn't specify units that way in labels but as a fraction, so correct would be `L/\si{\metre}`.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18357/are-there-any-guidelines-for-labeling-axes-in-plots-graphs

Comment: @Skillmon, I see what you mean, but I‘m not convinced. Let me add a plot to my answer below later today, so we can stop chatting here.

Answer (score 2):

### TOC

- Shortcut
- Quantity algebra
- NIST - approach
- Definition and history
- About my early answer (also deals with the log-question)
- Example
- Unchanged proposed early-morning **solution**

### Shortcut

Ask for your specific guidelines:

- if you write a thesis, your institute may want to follow a certain style
- if you want to publish, different publishers may have similar, yet different approaches
- if you write a data sheet, the associated company may demand a certain style
- if you write just for fun, follow your onw style

It's unregulated, non-standardized, and people try making the best out of it.

I.e., what I wrote early this morning is just a fine way to do it: as fine as alternatives.

### Quantity algebra

What Skillmon indicated is the topic of quantity algebra: how to deal with a compound of `value (of) {A}` and `unit (of) [A]` to characterize a `quantity A`?

It seems to be hard to find, let's say, a book on this subject, which presents worldwide agreed and tested-by-time rules. Rather, this subject is perhaps not settled yet. That's my indication from reviewing:

- Skillmons [link](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18357/are-there-any-guidelines-for-labeling-axes-in-plots-graphs) in one [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695793/units-when-the-axis-is-the-log?noredirect=1#comment1727544_695793)
- Wikipedia on [Quantity calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity_calculus)
- the next two sections

However, at least the algebraic convention about `quantity A` (see above) seems to be in common use.

### NIST - approach

Now, [NIST 2008](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication811e2008.pdf) treats quantity algebra this way:
[image: NIST]

- orange: common **definition**, implicitely read with a * between value and unit
- red: the "obvious" "**division**" (pragmatically ok, mathematically urrghhh ...)
- green: **consequences**, even a proposla for logarithmic notation

This seems to be what Skillmon suggested. However, there is a tendency to create eye-candy. The screenshot shows for inline equetions, which are quite small, while it won't be much better as a labeled axis.

[image: Skillmon]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{from Skillmon's comment}
    \si{\siemens\per\metre} 
    
    you could label your axis as: $\log(\frac{\sigma}{\qty{1}{\siemens\per\metre}})$
    
    or: $\log(\frac{\sigma}{\si{\siemens\per\metre}}) $
    
    or with a slash instead of the \emph{frac}, so: $\log(\sigma / \si{\siemens\per\metre})$
\end{document}
```

### Definition and history

I admit, I love this one ["The Algebraic Structure of Quantity Calculus" (2018)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1515/msr-2017-0021), which is a real mathematical treatment of quantity algebra. To remind ourselves, [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra)  is *the reunion of broken parts* (Arabic).

After a short intro into history of this problem, ot tries tackling this algebra by mapping (morphisms), groups etc. When scanning the document, the search for a `Divisor` (in mathematical terms) is a central concern, and it's far from NIST's innocent `/` ...

[image: math]

- yellow: **definition**, including the 3 basic operations from reality
- blue: **motivation** this paper
- green: a **long history** behind, yet not settled

*(If sbdy has access to Boer's paper, I'd be happy if s/he could make it available.)*

### About my early answer

Now, looking at the common definition of quantity q as:

q = {q} [q]

a logical interpretation of (more practically motivated) operators are:

- apply { } to q to read its value
- apply [ ] to q to read its unit

So these questions would be logical:

- which unit has my quantity L? It's [L] = 1 m (printed, `\metre` or `\meter` in Latex)
- what's the value of my quantity L? It's {L} = 3.4 nm

And this is one way to put it a step further:

- definition: L = {L} [L]
- result: L = {3.4} [nm] = {3.4} nm = 3.4 [nm] = 3.4 nm

There seems to be no apparent reason, to favor any one of these 4 combinations over the others. It's more reasonable `to consider them being equivalent`.

Hence, they might be used as deemed useful. The left one puts the most emphasis (marking value as value, unit as unit), while the last is relaxed. Equivalents.

When you follow this thought, other notations like from NIST above:

- 3.4 / nm
- 3.4 / (nm)

seem to be less logical, in my view. So NIST's argument of dividing `/` becomes more a syntactical element of style ... It's not bad, it's a difference, perhaps some inconsistency in their logic.

But we want to typeset. Let's do it.

Following this route further, to give **one possible answer to the OP's question**, one might argue:

- we have `quantity q`
- which shall be logarthmic (or any other useful transformation)
- so what could `lg q` reasonably mean?
- lg q = lg({q} [q]) = lg({q}) [q], because you just transform the value {q} for visual reasons only, leaving quantity q unchanged, i.e. keeping its unit [q]
- which suggests sth. like in this screenshot:

[image: lg(q)]

As a side-effect, it's much harder to create eye-candy this way.

### Example

Let's have a final look into guidelines, say for publishing in a physics journal. They provide an interesting idea, which somewhat follows my line of thought above. This one is from [PHYSICAL REVIEW JOURNALS](https://journals.aps.org/authors/axis-labels-and-scales-on-graphs-h18). Kindly recognize the brackets `[` and `]`.

[image: physrev]

So, whatever you decide to use, be logical and consistent.

---

Ok, the **SOLUTION** is rooted in the way we use units: just label all axes as „ [unit]“ pairs.

Say, you measure a length L over time t. So, what are their units? In Si we understand:

- [L] = 1 m, „the unit of L is meters“
- [t] = 1 s, „the unit of t is seconds“

While we also could measure e.g. L in a different system, like

- [L] = 1 ft, „the unit of L is feet“

So even on a simple xy plot L(t) it would be wise to lable axis like this:

- Y: „L [m]“ (or „L [ft]“)
- X: „t [m]“

This way we make sure two things:

- units, hence measurement is clear for both axis (measure a length, measure a time)
- they ONLY show the measured values, which have no dimension

So transforming one or both axis, e.b by lg or sqrt, doesn‘t hurt, as long as you label „L [m]“ on the axis. Now what you communicate e.g. for the Y-axis is:

- I measured a length L
- its unit was meters
- I rescaled its values to better see whatEver.

Comment: I don't want to get in an argument but I believe @Skillmon is talking [about this topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/28918). In my words (and also in my opinion, though): table headers and axis labels should be written so that they equal the content of the columns and of the ticks. So when the tick says 5 and it stands for a length of 5m, the axis label needs to be *L* /m because 5 = *L* /m ⇔ 5 m = *L*. So, on your log your axis where 2 stands for *L* = 100 m then 2 = lg₁₀(*L* /m) so the label is lg₁₀(*L* /m).

Comment: To get into an argument: In my opinion “*L* [m]” is nonsensical but, unfortunately, widely used and IIRC the accepted norm in that one big country that doesn't use SI units much in the day-to-day-life anyway.